# i'm struggling with the R package leaflet and i keep getting this error

Tags: r

read.csv(tweetsfortnite, "C:\Users\Miriam\Documents\tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
'file' must be a character string or connection.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `read.csv()` is `file` and should be a string representing the file path. I'm not on windows, but I think on windows you also need to switch the backward slashes to forward slashes or use two backward slashes in file paths.

Try this:

```
tweetsfortnite <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Miriam\\Documents\\tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Or:

```
tweetsfortnite <- read.csv("C:/Users/Miriam/Documents/tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```